# Saving data in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I want to save this data in the PostgresDB.

```
data={'apple',4,2,5,['question'],('answer')}
```

I have defined a field in the database as 'data' with the datatype as 'text'. 
When I am trying to save this data with this query:

```
UPDATE mydb 
   SET col1="{'apple',4,2,5,['question'],('answer')}" 
where id=123;
```

its giving me error. How can I save the data?

Comment: In SQL, string constants need to be enclosed in single quotes (`'`) not double quotes: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS  Double quotes (`"`) are for [identifiers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS)

Comment: why dont you store it as json?

Comment: @BenH For JSON, is the only change required is changing the datatype of data as 'json' or anything more is to be done? 
and how data needs to be send?
I am a newbie to postgres!

Comment: it depends on what you choose to do with your data, and where it comes from

Comment: @BenH data is random coming from various sources in my application.
data is of the form as given above.
i just want to store the data.

Comment: @S You do not want to do anything with your data? then why even store it (in a database). Do your application directly access the database?

Comment: @BenH yes. application is accessing db directly on this source. this data is coming from some other source.

Comment: @BenH this is the actual data:::
{'[{"info": "No", "uid": null, "links": ["<link rel='parent' title='project' href='http://example.com/project/1'/>", "<link rel='parent' title='task' href='http://example.com/task/1'/>"], "task_id": 1, "created": "2017-02-15T09:07:09.068145", "finish_time": "2017-02-15T09:07:14.620174", "calibration": null, "user_ip": null, "timeout": null, "project_id": 1, "id": 1}]', 'uuid': u'abc:def:ghi'}

Comment: so you got a json containing an array of one json, and text

Comment: @BenH yes. it contains both

Comment: @BenH Any Solution for this ?

Comment: you could store your json, and the text in the table

Comment: @BenH I tried that. But it's giving error something like this:
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "info"
LINE 1: UPDATE mydb SET data = """{'[{"info": "No", "exter...
I have the datatype of data as 'text'

Answer (score 0):

String literals in SQL are denoted by single quotes (`'`), not double quotes (`"`). Since your string contains single quotes, you'll have to escape them by doubling them (i.e., having two in a row - `''`, **not** converting them to double quotes):

```
UPDATE mydb 
   SET col1 = '{''apple'',4,2,5,[''question''],(''answer'')}' 
WHERE  id = 123;
```